# QGIS has Unknown CRS from GeoTIFF created with Python GDAL

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, gdal

I've been creating geotiffs using Python GDAL 2.4, here is a minimal example of my code:

```
from osgeo import gdal, osr

driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')

dataset = driver.Create("test.tif", 20, 10, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)
dataset.SetGeoTransform((500000, 5, 0, 100000, 0, -5))

srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromEPSG(27700)
dataset.SetProjection(srs.ExportToWkt())

dataset = None
```

I can then attempt to view this GeoTIFF in QGIS (3.12.1).  If I use the above code using GDAL 3.0, then the CRS is recognised, that is, in the layer properties I see:

```
EPSG:27700 - OSGB 1936 / British National Grid - Projected
```

as I expected.  However, I had been using GDAL 2.4, and using the above code gives:

```
Unknown CRS: BOUNDCRS[SOURCECRS[PROJCRS["OSGB 1936 / British National Grid",BASEGEOGCRS["OSGB 1936",DATUM["OSGB 1936",ELLIPSOID["Airy 1830",6377563.396,299.3249646,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],ID["EPSG",4277]],CONVERSION["British National Grid",METHOD["Transverse Mercator",ID["EPSG",9807]],PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",49,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8801]],PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",-2,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8802]],PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996012717,SCALEUNIT["unity",1],ID["EPSG",8805]],PARAMETER["False easting",400000,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],ID["EPSG",8806]],PARAMETER["False northing",-100000,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],ID["EPSG",8807]]],CS[Cartesian,2],AXIS["(E)",east,ORDER[1],LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],AXIS["(N)",north,ORDER[2],LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],USAGE[SCOPE["unknown"],AREA["UK - Britain and UKCS 49�46'N to 61�01'N, 7�33'W to 3�33'E"],BBOX[49.75,-9.2,61.14,2.88]],ID["EPSG",27700]]],TARGETCRS[GEOGCRS["WGS 84",DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],CS[ellipsoidal,2],AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,ORDER[1],ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,ORDER[2],ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],USAGE[SCOPE["unknown"],AREA["World"],BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],ID["EPSG",4326]]],ABRIDGEDTRANSFORMATION["Transformation to WGS84",METHOD["Position Vector transformation (geog2D domain)",ID["EPSG",9606]],PARAMETER["X-axis translation",446.448,ID["EPSG",8605]],PARAMETER["Y-axis translation",-125.157,ID["EPSG",8606]],PARAMETER["Z-axis translation",542.06,ID["EPSG",8607]],PARAMETER["X-axis rotation",0.15,ID["EPSG",8608]],PARAMETER["Y-axis rotation",0.247,ID["EPSG",8609]],PARAMETER["Z-axis rotation",0.842,ID["EPSG",8610]],PARAMETER["Scale difference",0.999979511,ID["EPSG",8611]]]] - Projected
```

Why is there a difference?

And also, why does QGIS does not recognise the version from GDAL 2.4?

---

Just to add to the above. I tried to see if there was a difference in the definition of the spatial refs in the geotiffs. I used `dataset.GetSpatialRef().ExportToProj4()` on the datasets above and they yielded:

```
'+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +units=m +no_defs' # gdal 3
'+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489 +units=m +no_defs' # gdal 2.4
```

Note that the only difference is the presence of `towgs84` in the gdal 2.4 version.

Is this relevant to the problem I'm seeing?